# include external script tags from other file

Tags: javascript

i have lots of common js files on the different 10 pages like this:

```
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
```

i want to put these tags one page then include only these page to other 10 pages.

For example commontags page include

```
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
```

tags then other 10 pages include

```
<script src="commontags"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with script tags alone, but you can do this with a templating engine, build step, or a module loader like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) or [curl.js](https://github.com/cujojs/curl).

I would highly suggest using Requirejs, and the requirejs [optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) if you are going to be loading more than a few js files. It will help keep your code modular, and the optimizer will make things nice and performant : )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with client side JavaScript, then store the URLs in an array, loop over them and generate a new element each time with `document.createElement` and `document.head.appendChild`.

Generally speaking, however, you'd be better off handling this by running the files through a combiner and minifier at build time so you have a single URL pointing to a single JS file containing all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Also this tool does this:
http://damonsmith.github.io/js-class-loader/

disclaimer: - I wrote it.